# Choosing Firestore Collections that need to be synced

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am unable to find details of how Firebase Firestore chooses what to cache locally. The documentation is vague about this. It says that Firestore caches data that the `app is actively using`.

My requirement is that I need to explicitly set specific collections to be cached locally on the device. Is it possible to do it with Firestore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My requirement is that I need to explicitly set specific collections to be cached locally on the device.

There is no way you can specify which collection may exist in cache and which not. By default, Firestore caches all data that your application reads. It's all or nothing.

> Is it possible to do it with Firestore?

No, it's not.

Comment: "By default, Firestore caches all your data." That's a bit oversimplified, and easy to misunderstand. Firestore caches all data **that your application reads**. That is usually significantly less than all data in the database. See my answer here for more on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55590838/how-does-firestore-persistence-really-work/55594373#55594373

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You're right and thanks again for making it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for answering folks. So is it correct to assume that all data that is read/written by my application will continue to be cached by the SDK?

Comment: @pcx Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a ton Alex! could you please update your answer for clarity. I have marked it as correct.

Comment: @pcx Yep, just did. Thanks!