# Firestore: If two listeners listening the same query firebase maintains two different query snap shots?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We are building a job portal. We have a `applications` collection where we create a document when a user applies for a job.

Now, from Android app client, I am listening to the same collection in two different activities. I have enabled the local persistence too.

Now, does Firebase understand that it is the same query triggered from two activities and maintains one query snapshot for the listener or does it create two snapshots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, does the Firebase manages to understand its the same query happening from two activities and maintains one query snapshot for the listener or it creates two snapshots?

Since you say that you have enabled the local persistence, it means that Firebase will create a local copy of the requested documents on the user's device. So with this persistence enabled, while offline, it doesn't really matter the number of activities from which you perform the same query, you'll always get the data from the cache.

As @brianbhsu pointed out in his comment, while **online**, you'll always query the online Firestore instance so you'll always have the data up to date.

As also Frank van Puffelen mentioned in his answer, Firestore doesn't store all available data locally automatically:

- [How does Firestore persistence really work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55590838/how-does-firestore-persistence-really-work)

@Mangesh If you query from two different activities using two different `Query` objects, then those queries will be treated as two different queries.

Comment: Thanks. How does the client decide what data to store in its local persistence? Is it based on the listeners I have created in the activities?

Comment: You cannot choose what data to store, it's all or nothing. And you're very welcome, cheers!

Comment: I am now confused about the all or nothing part. If the database has 10 collections and a million documents in them, the client is going to have the whole database? What if some of the collections are used for internal purposes. And how does security rules that block users from accessing other user's documents work here? The official document says, "When persistence is enabled, Cloud Firestore caches every document received from the backend for offline access."

Comment: You cannot store only parts of your database. If you have 10 collections, all 10 will be stored in the cache. You cannot tell Firestore which collection to store or not in cache. If you have million of documents it's almost impossible to get all of them at once. And the documentation is right.

Comment: From my experience with Firestore using Flutter, the Firestore library always queries the online Firestore instance if the client is connected to the internet regardless of whether local persistence is enabled or not (it is enabled by default in the Flutter library). You have to set a parameter to specifically tell the library to only query the local cache. Is that not the default behavior in other libraries as well?

Comment: Also, I don't think Firestore stores all available data locally automatically. I think this behavior wouldn't make sense otherwise the connected device could very easily have storage issues. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55590838/how-does-firestore-persistence-really-work

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for updating your answer! I retracted the down-vote.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the `understand its the same query happening from two activities` part. Is the same query from different activities is treated as one?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for the update. So, lets say `Activity` or `Fragment` is being recreated, and since we fire query in `onStart()`, does it mean we are charged every time regardless of the 30 min duration (because new `Query` object will be created)?

Comment: @Mangesh This article, **[How to drastically reduce the number of reads when no documents are changed in Firestore?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e)** will answer all your questions regarding queries and billing.

Comment: @AlexMamo The article mainly talks about `get` operation, whereas this question is about real-time listeners. As per your answer update, we are charged for every new `Query` object. Ergo my question, then are we charged for every Fragment Transaction? Because, it is very common to replace fragments while navigating through different parts of the app. In such cases, each fresh query would be costly and 30 min duration for single object makes no sense. My understanding was, it is 30 min for each `Query`, regardless of which object triggered it because its still asking for same set of documents.

Comment: @Mangesh That's a topic that cannot be covered in a comment. So please post a question for that using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can take a look at it.

Comment: @AlexMamo Here you go https://stackoverflow.com/q/63033423/3273962