# Firebase - Cloud firestore works offline?

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to working with apps so thanks for any answer.

I'm using react native and firestore cloud. I want to know if it is possible for the application to work offline using firestore cloud. Currently the application fetches the data and updates it, in addition to working by authentication (email and password).

Initially I created the application without thinking about using it offline, but now I see that it is necessary, any alternative is valid for me.

Comment: Since "cloud = someone's else computer" it's simply not posible to access it entirely offline. You can implement a local cache to avoid fetching data and you can save it locally, if no other users need access to it. Or implement some sort of "save locally until online, then publish to the "cloud"", but ultimately the end result is that you can't access an online DB while being offline.

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks for the answer. Is there any other way to log in, and the whole app is functional without internet? It doesn't have to be firebase

Comment: It depends, what the "login" does? Without internet access you're restricted to the local hard disk, so the users have to come from your own computer, or be delivered with your program. In general if you want to be 100% offline you need your installer to contain every single asset you can ever use, and don't ask for anything outside the computer it runs. It also means no updates are possible to online data of any kind.

Comment: @Alejandro I understood. In firebase I was using login email/password (no authentication by other apps). It looks like this will be impossible using firebase, I'm looking for other options. I thought about connecting the user only once (using internet) and, when using the application again, being able to use it completely offline. Thanks for feedback

Comment: There's an available Firebase guide on how you can [enable offline data](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline). Additionally, you can check the answer from this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55594373/16531380) that further explains the documentation that I linked.